# Different result from $((++n)) when running bash vs dash

Tags: bash, shell, dash-shell

I'm getting different outputs when running the program in bash and dash

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $SHELL
n=1
a=$((++n))
echo $n
```

Bash:

```
$ bash shell_test.sh
2
```

Dash:

```
$ dash shell_test.sh
1
```

Answer (score 7):

`dash` is the *Debian Almquist shell* and an extreme light-weight version of a full POSIX-compliant shell-implementation of `/bin/sh` that aims to be as small as possible creating faster bootup times.

Operators such as `$((n++))`, `$((--n))` and similar are features that are not required by POSIX and therefore not implemented.

To see how dash interprets these statements, see [Chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52481142/8344060)

A nice page explaining how to make your script POSIX compliant, is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

---

> **2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion:**  Arithmetic expansion provides a mechanism for evaluating an arithmetic expression and substituting its value. The format for arithmetic expansion shall be as follows:
>
> ```
> $((expression))
> ```
>
> The expression shall be treated as if it were in double-quotes, except that a double-quote inside the expression is not treated specially. The shell shall expand all tokens in the expression for parameter expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.
>
> Next, the shell shall treat this as an arithmetic expression and substitute the value of the expression. The arithmetic expression shall be processed according to the rules given in [Arithmetic Precision and Operations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02_01), **with the following exceptions:**
>
> - Only signed long integer arithmetic is required.
> - Only the decimal-constant, octal-constant, and hexadecimal-constant constants specified in the ISO C standard, Section 6.4.4.1 are required to be recognized as constants.
> - The `sizeof()` operator and **the prefix and postfix `++` and `--` operators are not required.**
> - Selection, iteration, and jump statements are not supported.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX IEEE Std 1003.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)</sub>**

Answer (score 6):

Prefix `++` is not required by POSIX, and `dash` doesn't implement it. Instead, it's parsed as two unary `+` operators:

```
$ n=1
$ echo $((+(+n)))
1
$ echo $((++n))
1
$ echo $n
1
```